# RSpec testing a gem providing a support spec

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, rubygems

I have a support spec function which handles testing routing over actions, formats, associations. This code has been moved to our backend gem. Makes route testing in the main app much cleaner. I'm trying to add more robust unit testing to the module since two projects are using it.

I would like to write an RSpec test in the gem to test the RSpec code provided by the gem.

In our gem (`<gem>/lib/<gem>/spec/support/file.rb`) it does something like

```
def test_route(....)
  ...
  if routable
    specify 'message' do
      expect (method => url).to route_to(controller, route_hash)
    end
  else
    specify 'other message' do
      expect (method => url).not_to be_routable
    end
  end
end
```

In the gem rspec (`<gem>/spec/lib/spec/support/test_route_spec.rb`), 
I've tried to stub out the `:define_example_method` function, but I'm not getting anywhere:

```
context 'context message' do
  before do
    allow(RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup).to receive(:define_example_group).with(name)
  end
  specify do
     # /b/1/a.json should be routable
     test_route(:a, :b, :index, :json, true)
     # expect something....
  end
end
```

I end up with the following:

```
`specify` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block)...
```

which is coming from the method_missing method

Any guidance or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok. So using RSpec while trying to mock out parts of rspec, especially, trying to mock specify within a specify is just a brain dead idea. Ended up making a specify_wrapper(message, &block) that calls specify message, &block and mock the wrapper and do expectations on that.